# Many to Many to Many Database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am fairly new with database design so thank you for all input for helping me with a little problem I have designing the structure of a database. Basically I want to set up a many-to-many-to-many relationship between 3 main tables and a forth that is linked to the third. I'll try to explain it using an example.

Suppose I have tables created to show the relationship between SCENE, ACTOR, and ACTION. SCENE can have more than one ACTOR, and each ACTOR can have more than one ACTION. This is what I have worked out so far:

Have an intermediate ScenesActors table that just lists the SceneID and ActorID (along with its own ID field [SceneActorID] as primary key).

You then have the ScenesActorsActions table which has the SceneActorID and ActionID (along with its own ID field [SceneActorActionID] as PK).

The ScenesActors table lists each actors are in which scenes.

The ScenesActorsActions table lists what they do.

Scenes --< ScenesActors >-- Actors

Actions --< ScenesActorsActions

However, in the design of my database, say Actions already has a one-to-many relationship with another table titled ActionPossibilities in which every row was a possible action that could take place (essentially making the possible actions that could occur dynamic). How then would you effectively create the relationship described above? The problem i am running into is that the primary key for the Actions table is used as a foreign key in the ActionPossibilities table. Is something like this possible under the current design?

Answer (score 0):

Just have four tables:  Scene, Actor, Action and ActionPossibilities.  Scene and Actor should be simple: SceneID, SceneDescription, etc.  Same for Actor.  Action is your main table.  It should have a FKs to SceneID, ActorID, and ActionPossibilitiesID (not the other way around). From there, you can query Action to get whatever combination of actors/scenes/actions you need.